# Anchor jump issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a small app using flask but facing some issue during anchor jump. Here is the Jquery I am using on page load

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#{{myAnchor}}').offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    });
</script>
```

myAnchor is generating dynamically.

HTML anchor

```
<a id = "anchor-{{my_post.id}}">
                    anchor-{{my_post.id}}
                </a>
```

once the page loading its is scroll to wrong position. you can say 2 or 3 anchor position down. Note I am using for loop in the template.  Any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you have duplicate IDs?

Comment: My guess is content is still loading so element heights change?

Comment: no the ID are unique as I am naming it with DB primary -key.

Comment: Keep in mind "its nightmare" to use Jquery (Or js) to control the scroll position combine with an anchor link (Conflicts - because the #ancor already set the scroll position). This is why one solution is to use `event.preventDefault();`. Basic example her: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2

Comment: I have to jump to the specific anchor on page loading.